# Meaning of valid Salat

Tags: salat

We are taught how to perform Salat prayer properly and for me it's out of question to try to do so.
However, I often encounter questions on this site whether if so-and-so, the prayer is valid.

What does it mean whether a prayer is valid? Valid for what?

All teachings are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Valid for fulfilling the obligation. There are some conditions for validity of Salah as well as some actions which are an essential part of Salah. If someone performs salah and does not take care of those then his salah is invalid. This means that he needs to fix the problem and redo the salah properly. Some examples of matters which may invalidate salah include for example if a person:

- prays in a state of ritual impurity, without doing wudu.
- prays while naked.
- prays with his back turned towards the qiblah
- does not perform an essential pillar of prayer, e.g. he completely omitted prostration.
- starts laughing, talking, eating or doing something else during prayer

For further details see e.g.  [Islamic Jurisprudence According To The Four Sunni Schools (page 379 - 385)](https://archive.org/details/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah/page/378/mode/2up?view=theater)

Comment: Hello UmH. Your answer and the link  is good for the teachings how to pray properly. These are are human teachings going back to a long tradition. But my question is rather to whom (the Imam) or to Whom (God) it is taught to be "valid", and from where the authority comes to determine this.

Comment: Your comment is unclear I am going to respond based on my guess of what you are saying. Only God has the authority to legislate, everything that is a part of Islam comes from God and is based on the interpretation of the Quran or Sunnah. For example the first example I mentioned is based on [this](https://quran.com/5/6) and [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim:225).